# How to set first name & last name for guest customer order in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, guest-checkout

In the guest order info customer name displaying as a guest and looked into the database table of `sales_order` here customer first name & last name storing as a null.

how can we set name before place order?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create one observer file :

> Namespace\Module\Observer\SalesOrderPlaceBefore.php

```
namespace Namespace\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SalesOrderPlaceBefore implements ObserverInterface
{

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        if (!$order->getCustomerFirstname() && !$order->getCustomerLastname()) {
            $order->setCustomerFirstname($order->getBillingAddress()->getFirstname());
            $order->setCustomerLastname($order->getBillingAddress()->getLastname());
        }
        $order->save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating an observer similar to 'AssignOrderToCustomerObserver.php' in sales module.

```
$order->setCustomerFirstname($customer->getFirstname())
      ->setCustomerLastname($customer->getLastname())
```

This should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, $customer->getFirstname() getting as blank value and I was solved by using observer after place order.

Comment: Good to know :)